# Eu preciso fazer a formatação assim que a página carregar, mas não conheço outro atributo do html que faça isso, estou usando oninput

Tags: php, javascript, html, input, onclick

html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="preco" id="preco" oninput="mascaraMoeda(event)" value="<?= $value->preco; ?>">
```

javascript:

```
function mascaraMoeda(event) {
    const onlyDigits = event.target.value
        .split("")
        .filter(s => /\d/.test(s))
        .join("")
        .padStart(3, "0")
    const digitsFloat = onlyDigits.slice(0, -2) + "." + onlyDigits.slice(-2)
    event.target.value = maskCurrency(digitsFloat)
}

function maskCurrency(valor, locale = 'pt-BR', currency = 'BRL') {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {
        style: 'currency',
        currency
    }).format(valor)
}
```

php: Os dados estão sendo puxados do mysql com o php

Answer (score -2):

Como não especificou exatamente como quer que seja exibido o valor, vou supor que queira nesse estilo: R$1.000,00

Primeiro você pode formatar o $valor em php:

```
$valor = number_format($valor,2,",",".");
```

Utilize onchange no lugar de oninput e no javascript é necessário transformar o valor em float, utilizando parseFloat, exemplo:

```js
    function mascaraMoeda(event){
       formatedNumber = parseFloat(event.target.value).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
       event.target.value = formatedNumber;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="preco" id="preco" onChange="mascaraMoeda(event)" value="">
```